# AWS auto scaling group origin server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

How can I keep the origin or the oldest EC2 instance in AWS auto scaling group while termination?
Auto scaling group has launched 5 servers on the basis of some scaling policies.

I want to know how can I implement the termination policy, so that the oldest server never get terminated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the AWS documentation for this.

Choosing a Termination Policy for Your Auto Scaling Group

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/AutoScalingBehavior.InstanceTermination.html

Specifically, you want `NewestInstance`, which terminates the newest instances.

Comment: This is kind of vague. An explanation of how termination policies work might be a good idea

Answer (score 1):

You can protect your oldest/origin server by going to **Auto Scaling group** and in the instances tab  right click instance(oldest/origin server) and from Instance Protection then select **Set Scale In Protection** it will prevent system from terminating during scale in process.

Answer (score -1):

U can try this aws documentation

http://docs.amazonaws.cn/en_us/AutoScaling/latest/DeveloperGuide/us-termination-policy.html#your-termination-policy

as-create-auto-scaling-group asg-test-termination-policy --launch-configuration lc-test-termination-policy --availability-zones "us-east-1e" --max-size 3 --min-size 1 –desired-capacity 2 -–termination-policies “NewestInstance”